# How to filter a PostgreSQL database name via the kubectl command?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm using a kubernetes and want to filter only the **sampledb** on my postgreSQL.

I tried to use this command:

```
kubectl exec podname-89tq4763k23-klp83 -- bash -c "psql -U postgres --tuples-only -P format=unaligned -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE NOT datistemplate AND datname <> 'postgres'";"
```

but it does not show any output from my terminal, my expectation is it should show **sampledb** as an output

Tried using this command to list all databasename and it is working.

```
kubectl exec -it podname-89tq4763k23-klp83 -- psql -U postgres -c "\l"
```

my question is how can I filter only the **sampledb** name from the list of databases?

```
                                                 List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges
-------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------
 sampledb    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            |
 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            |
 template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |            |            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |            |            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Note: I'm also planning to use this kubectl command if it works as a variable for my bash script.

Comment: You obviously need to escape the nested quotation marks somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer to the question.

my command just need a quoting fix.

previous command used:

```
kubectl exec podname-89tq4763k23-klp83 -- bash -c "psql -U postgres --tuples-only -P format=unaligned -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE NOT datistemplate AND datname <> 'postgres'";"
```

new command used.

```
kubectl exec $POD -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -t -A -c \"SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE NOT datistemplate AND datname <> 'postgres'\""
```

for detailed syntax [postgresql app-psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

Comment: Hi, your answer really needs an explanation, here, for future visitors.

Comment: done adding explanation.